# MongoDB findOne vs find using $in with single item

Tags: mongodb, performance, find

I am using MongoClient on a NodeJS service.

As part of improving my service's performance I want to determine if I should act differently when handling with single id vs with multiple ids in the terms of querying Mongo.

My current code looks like this:

`collection.find({ id: {$in: ids } })`

I wanted to know if I would split the code to handle single id separately would make the performance any better, somewhat like this:

`if ids.count == 1
    collection.findOne({ id: ids.first })
else
    collection.find({ id: {$in: ids } })
end`

Comment: use the explain() function on your queries so you can compare execution time. You can do it from the shell like this: db.collection.findOne({_id:  "id"}).explain();

Comment: Thanks @felix, I have used `explain()` and running `find({ id: { $in: [ some_id ]) }` and `find({ id: some_id })` results with the same winningPlan! :)

Answer (score 0):

According with MongoDB Driver for NodeJS, findOne is deprecated in favour of find().

*Deprecated, use find().limit(1).next(function(err, doc){}) instead*

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Collection.html#findOne

Even more, `findOne()` is syntax sugar of `find().limit(1).toArray()`

I strongly suggest you to take a look if something is deprecated before use it in production [at that link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/)

Comment: `findOne` is not my main focus here.I am debating if using `find` with `{ id: { $in: [ some_id ] }`, meaning array containing one item only vs `find` with `{ id: some_id }` would have any affect on performance.

Comment: @BarakHarizi If you want to benchmark then you should avoid deprecated function. I tested with $in and without $in and the results are absolutely comparable (1ms vs 1ms). Related to the better approach: "use what you need". So personally i can suggest to avoid $in as better approach more then as "better/improvement" speed.

Comment: I have used explain() to get better understanding of what winning plan it(mongo) actually runs, and it's the same winning plan, therefore I've decided not to separate by single/multiple approach.

Comment: Doesn't look like findOne is deprecated any more.  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOne